# Python3 - copying blocks of text from one text to write into another

Tags: python

I have an input.txt file that I am parsing through in order to grab certain lines of text. I am currently using this to grab lines of the text file that I want, but I want to start grabbing the text when it spots a triple quote (`'''`) and stop when it sees another triple quote preferably maintaining the spacing within.

```
plist = []
with open('input.txt', "r") as input_file, open('output.txt', "w") as output_file:
for line in inputFile:
    if(line.startswith('a:')):
        newLine = line.strip('p:').strip()
        plist.append('text block "' + newLine.strip('\"'))
```

what I want to copy:

```
a: '''
{
  hello
    hi
  goodbye
}
'''
```

what I want to get:

```
{
  hello
    hi
  goodbye
}
```

My current way of doing this only grabs a single line of text

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
f1 = open('input.txt', "r")
# Read complete files at once
data = f1.read()
# data = ": a: ''' { hello hi goodbye } '''"

# get a list of all the strings inside the triple quote
res = re.findall("'''.*?'''", data)
print(res)
# Output: ["''' { hello hi goodbye } '''"]
for i in res: print(i.replace("'''", ""))
# Output: { hello hi goodbye }
```

Comment: Please provide more information about how your answer solves OP question. How your code works...?

Comment: Have edited the answer, check now